# Print whole address block of some variable

Tags: c, pointers, hex, memory-address

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 56;
    printf("First part of address block:\n");
    printf("%p", &a);
    printf("All parts of address block:\n");
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p", &a, &a + 1, &a + 2, &a + 3);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
First part of address block:                                                        
0x7fffd029ecec                                                                               
All parts of address block:                                                                             
0x7fffd029ecec                                                                               
0x7fffd029ecf0                                                                               
0x7fffd029ecf4                                                                               
0x7fffd029ecf8
```

In my opinion, address block of int a looks like this:

```
| 0x7fffd029ece**c** | 0x7fffd029ece**d** | 0x7fffd029ece**e** | 0x7fffd029ece**f** |
|      0000          |      0000          |      0011          |      1000
```

Comment: `int` commonly has a size of `4`, so that output looks right to me.

Comment: You might want to read about "pointer arithmetics".

Comment: You must cast to `void *` to get the proper type for `%p`. Also, print the size of `a` (`printf("my int is %zu bytes\n", sizeof a);`) to make sure.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

C increment pointers not by bytes, but by size of type is pointed on. 
That is, if you have pointer to int it increments by sizeof(int) - in your example is 4.

Comment: When I have char a = 'A' and do the same thing as in my post: &a + 1, will it be +1? Am I right?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, since `sizeof(char)` is always 1

Answer (score 0):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359607/print-whole-address-block-of-some-variable/55359701#55359701) said, pointer math increments by the size of the type, not the byte.

You can make it meet your expectation by casting `&a` to a `char*` (aka. byte-pointer):

```
int main(void) {
    int a = 56;
    printf("First part of address block:\n");
    printf("%p", &a);
    printf("All parts of address block:\n");
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p", &a, ((char*)&a) + 1, ((char*)&a) + 2, ((char*)&a) + 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I'd write it to make it handle the platform size:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 56;
    char* p = (char*)&a;
    printf("First part of address block:\n");
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    printf("All parts of address block:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a); ++i) printf("%p : [%d] : 0x%02x\n", p+i, i, *(p+i));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
First part of address block:
0x7ffff2e39c5c
All parts of address block:
0x7ffff2e39c5c : [0] : 0x38
0x7ffff2e39c5d : [1] : 0x00
0x7ffff2e39c5e : [2] : 0x00
0x7ffff2e39c5f : [3] : 0x00
```

Comment: Can you give me code how to print also value? If first part is 0000, value will be 0 ... last block is 1000, value will be 8. I tried `printf("Value: %d", *((char*)&a))`, but it does not work.